# download the svg file from DOM or from Object element

Tags: typescript, svg, angular7, svgpanzoom

I want to download/save .svg from the DOM. I have embedded my svg file in Object element and updating dynamically some of the elements inside SVG and styling it in my Angular 7 application.

```
<object id="svg1" data="assets/10026_019.svg" type="image/svg+xml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></object>
     <button (click)="downloadSVG()">Download SVG file</button>
```

After updating SVG I need to download/save the entire svg contnet in .svg file. or any other alternate options availble for to download updated svg file?

Answer (score 0):

I have done myself, but not sure whether this is correct approach. Below code works fine.
I have installed file saver package from npm

```
npm install file-saver ngx-filesaver --save
```

In app.module.ts we have to import and add it in imports array

```
import { FileSaverModule } from 'ngx-filesaver';
imports: [  
    FileSaverModule
  ]
```

and then in typescript we have to import filesaver like below

```
import { FileSaverService } from "ngx-filesaver";
```

from constructor we have to initialize the service

```
 constructor(private fileSaverService: FileSaverService){}
```

and then download function

```
downloadSvg(){    
    let obj:any=document.getElementById('svg1');
    let svgBody:any=obj.contentDocument.querySelector("svg").innerHTML;
    let svgContent="﻿<svg version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" viewBox=\"4239.54 906.94 3137 1984\">"+svgBody+"</svg>";
    let blob=new Blob([svgContent]);    
    this.fileSaverService.save(this.blob,'filename.svg');

  }
```